# Error : for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python

Why is this arises: for event in pygame.event.get(): pygame.error: video system not initialized, and if I put pygame.quite() outside of while loop then it stops working.(not able to quit)

```
import pygame
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Two Player Shooting Game!")
def main():
    run = True
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to edit two things:
First, you should call `pygame.init()` function after importing pygame.

> That basically initializes the modules that should be initialized.

Second, You should write `while run:` not `while True:`
so the code will be as following:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()  # ADDED

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Two Player Shooting Game!")
def main():
    run = True
    while run:  # EDITED
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

pygame should be initialized after you use any of its stuff, so u should do `pygame.init()` after importing it
then u didn't use the variable u edited which was `run` in the while loop